# Steps to Get Value from NSComboBox

Tags: macos, cocoa

im new to Cocoa Applications(Mac application) , im trying to get selected value from NSCombobox , i don't how to proceed, please help me on this, it will be better if steps are provided.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use `objectValueOfSelectedItem` and if that's `nil` the user has entered text that is not from the list, so use the `stringValue` method of the `NSControl` ancestor:

```
NSString *str = [_comboBox objectValueOfSelectedItem];
if (!str)
    str = [_comboBox stringValue];
```